# Tableview cell shaking when image size is too large

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to show image in fixed size area like 100*100 px but real image size is too large (like 400*450) , the problem is when I set large image in 100*100 px imageview  then scrolling produce shaking of cells

Comment: its called jerk. and please show your `cellForRow` method code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this single line of code to create a new UIImage which is scaled. Set the scale and orientation params to achieve what you want. The first line of code just grabs the image.

```
// grab the original image
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
// scaling set to 2.0 makes the image 1/2 the size. 
UIImage *scaledImage = 
            [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage] 
                          scale:(originalImage.scale * 2.0)
                             orientation:(originalImage.imageOrientation)];
```

The simplest way is to set the frame of your UIImageView and set the contentMode to one of the resizing options.

Or you can use this utility method, if you actually need to resize an image:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I used your first solution & its working almost fine on all devices (some old devices have still jerk problem) .

Comment: But I have a confusion  is your both solution is same or If I use your second one answer . would It give better solution . Plz suggest me Thanks

Comment: the first solution scale the image, but if you need to resize the image using the second option